# My app crashes on Android 6.0 or more

Tags: android, android-studio

[view this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0dnu.png)I have an application on Google Play Store of torch light but there is a problem (the app can't work properly on 6.0 Android model and above also). How can I make it to run on above Android system?

If the user run the app in 6.0 OS mobile the button is clicked the layout is changed but the touch light does not turn on, it's still in off state.

where you find the crash report of my torch light crashes report .

Link is as below:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.three.torchlight

Comment: Hi, can you edit to put some crashlog or repports :)

Comment: I am assuming your are not requesting the camera-permission at runtime, which is needed to use the flaslight. Look into runtime permissions

Comment: @MrLeblond i just run my app only in low ios model and it work properly but i do not test it still in 6.0 phone but in 5.1 or less it work properly

Comment: Rockney ok dear my mind said to me that i have set the max sdk 25 so i need to increase the sdk so my problem will solved but i have not tested yet.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rockney mentioned in the comments, you need to request (dangerous) permissions during the app's **runtime** for Android 6.0 and above as opposed to during the **installation** process at the Play Store for versions 5.1 and lower. Check it out [here in the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).